# SQL Trigger showing error

Tags: sql

I created two tables one by the name Courses whose create statement is as follows:

```
create table Courses
(
    CID int,
    Cname varchar(25),
    DepID int,
    No_Sems int,

    primary key(CID),
    foreign key(DepID) references Departments
);
```

Another is by the name `Departments` which is as follows:

```
create table Departments
( 
     DID int,
     Dname varchar(20),
     HOD_ID int, 
     No_Courses int,

     primary key (DID)
);
```

I wanted to increment `No_Courses` when a course is added into the `Courses` table. Hence I created the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER CourseInc
AFTER INSERT ON Courses
REFERENCING NEW AS NewCourse
    UPDATE Department 
    SET No_Courses = No_Courses + 1 
    WHERE DID = NewCourse.DepID
```

But I keep getting a message like this:

> ERROR at line 1: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting
>   one of the following:
>
> begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null
>   pragma raise return select update while with
>
> << close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe
>   The symbol "exit" was substituted for ";" to continue.
>   1. CREATE TRIGGER CourseInc
>   2. AFTER INSERT ON Courses
>   3. REFERENCING NEW AS NewCourse

I am not sure what is wrong. Please help.

Comment: can you post your full trigger? Try doing this->   :NewCourse.DepID

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: The error message indicates it's Oracle. Please see the manual for the correct syntax: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_trigger.htm#LNPLS2183 The manual also contains many examples with the correct syntax: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/triggers.htm#BCFBGFDJ

Comment: @cableload Tried it no effect